# Is it true that $x\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \prod_{n=1}^k \frac{x}{x+n}$ for $0<x<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I would like to prove or disprove $x\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \prod_{n=1}^k \frac{x}{x+n}$. From numerical examples it looks like the inequality holds. However, I have no idea how to prove it.

I have found a similar question 
[sum of an infinite series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \prod_{m=1}^k\frac{1}{1+m\gamma}\right) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998595/sum-of-an-infinite-series-sum-k-1-infty-left-prod-m-1k-frac11m-ga), where the function looks very similar to mine, but not the same.

Looking forward to any hints. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may help to know where this expression came from. Can you provide context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, the equality hold and it hold for any $x >0$.

$$\prod_{n=1}^k\frac{x}{x+n}=\frac{x^k}{(x+1)_k}$$ where appear Pochhammer symbols and 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \prod_{n=1}^k \frac{x}{x+n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k\,x^k}{(x+1)_k}=\frac{x^2\,\Gamma (x)}{\Gamma (x+1)}=x$$

Comment: Just a little nitpick: *any $x>0$*. (+1) anyway.

Comment: Sorry for this stupid comment. How does the second last equality follow? Thanks! @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. Thanks for pointing it !

Comment: I guess such identity is just part of the arsenal of Monsieur Leibovici, but for a proof from scratch, one might start by noticing that $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k x^k}{(x+1)_k}$ is a meromorphic function with potential simple poles at $-1,-2,-3,-4,\ldots$. By computing the residues (they're all zero) we get that those potential poles are regularity points, hence $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k x^k}{(x+1)_k}$ is an entire function fixed by its derivatives at the origin. This leads to $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k x^k}{(x+1)_k}=x$.

Comment: Then $\frac{k x^k}{(x+1)_k}$ is a positive function on any subset of $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence $\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k x^k}{(x+1)_k}<x$ for any $x>0$.

Answer (score 2):

For a proof of $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k x^k}{(x+1)_k}=x$ avoiding Complex Analysis, one might invoke Euler's Beta function.

$$\frac{1}{(x+1)_k}=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+k+1)}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}B(k,x+1)=\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\int_{0}^{1}u^{k-1}(1-u)^x\,du.$$
Multiplying both sides by $kx^k$ and summing over $k\geq 1$ we get

$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k x^k}{(x+1)_k} = \int_{0}^{1}(1-u)^x \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k x^k u^k}{(k-1)!}\cdot\frac{du}{u}=x\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)^x (1+ux)e^{ux}\,du$$
where the last integral does not really depend on $x$: it equals $1$ for any $x>0$, since the integrand function is $-\frac{d}{du}\left[(1-u)^{x+1}e^{ux}\right]$.